# Pass the same dataframe over and over again to different classes and functions in Python

Tags: python, pandas, structure

The first step of my program is to get the data.
After that I am finding myself passing this data to all the different classes (with also a config dictionary variable) over and over again.

So I am wondering if there is a better way to just store the data somewhere and make it available to all classes and functions, without passing them as a parameter.

Thank you

Edit: here is a code example

go.py

```
config = {
    'mode' : 'single',
    'data' : { },
    'strategy' : { },
    'view' : { }
}

stratego.start(config)
```

stratego.py

```
def start(config):

    data = dt.Data(config['data'])

    if (config['data']['type'] == 'yahoo'):
        df = data.get_yahoo_data()
    elif (config['data']['type'] == 'csv'):
        df = data.get_csv_data()
    else:
        return False

    trades = str.Strategy(df, config['strategy'])
    tradeBook = trades.run()
```

but then I am realising that the problem is my main function (start). If I run the main code not in a function I have all my instances available in the global. Is that right? Is it correct to do this way or it is better to wrap the program in a main function?

Comment: What's wrong with passing it as a parameter?

Comment: I assume you're using Pandas, so I added the [tag:pandas] tag for you.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi I do not really know, but while I am writing the code I feel something is wrong. I am quite new in Python, but thinking by what I saw in PHP there are places likes GLOBALS where to store data that is frequently requested, or an instance to request data from.

Answer (score 0):

If really you don't want to pass it as an argument you could define it as a variable in a python file and import this variable where you define your fonction. You should be able to use this variable in the function without passing it in argument.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Refactored code according to code update by OP

Ok since you use a strategy pattern you can actually do that using a strategy like design pattern

`stratego.py`

```py
def start(*strategies):
    for strategy in strategies:
        strategy.run()
```

`go.py`

```py
from functools import lru_cache, wraps
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
import stratego

@lru_cache()
def get_data(filepath):
    # Load data from filepath
    data = ...
    return data

@lru_cache()
def get_data_with_config(**data_config):
    # Load data based on data_config
    data = get_data(data_config['filepath'])

    if (data_config['type'] == 'yahoo'):
        df = data.get_yahoo_data()
    elif (data_config['type'] == 'csv'):
        df = data.get_csv_data()
    ...
    return df

class Strategy(ABC):
    def __init__(self, config):
        self.config = config

    @abstractmethod
    def run(self):
        pass

class YahooStrategy(Strategy):
    def __init__(self, config):
        config = config.copy()
        config['data']['type'] = 'yahoo'
        super().__init__(config)

    def run(self):
        df = get_data_with_config(**self.config['data'])
        # Do sth with data

class CsvStrategy(Strategy):
    def __init__(self, config):
        config = config.copy()
        config['data']['type'] = 'csv'
        super().__init__(config)

    def run(self):
        df = get_data_with_config(**self.config['data'])
        # Do sth with data

class FunctionStrategy(Strategy):
    def __init__(self, config, func):
        super().__init__(config)
        self.func = func
    
    def run(self):
        return self.func(self.config)
    
def strategy_decorator(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(config):
        return FunctionStrategy(config, func)
    return wrapper

@strategy_decorator
def some_strategy_function(config):
    df = get_data_with_config(**config['data'])
    # Do smth with data

# With one strategy
strategy = YahooStrategy({'data': {'filepath': 'data.csv', ...}})
stratego.run(strategy)

# Multiple strategies
strategies = [
    YahooStrategy({'data': {'filepath': 'data.csv', ...}}),
    CsvStrategy({'data': {'filepath': 'data2.csv', ...}}),
    some_strategy_function({'data': {'filepath': 'data4.csv', ...}})
]
stratego.run(*strategies)
```

Comment: Considering your first solution I am understanding that the code inside data.py is executed before it is imported. In my case I have main(config) function which requests data (based on config settings), and stores it in a variable the it is passed to all other classes. Saying that is it correct to have a file data.py where I declare an empty df. Then from my main functions I import this variable as global and fill it with the content of the data I get? And then from all others file I import it as from data import df. Thanks!

Comment: If you can post a sample code to the question to demonstrate how the logic works, maybe I can help you with appropriate code.

Comment: Yes you are right. I have just modified the post adding the code.

Comment: Ok I updated my answer let me know if this suits you.

Comment: Thank you for the effort in answering my question. There is a lot of arguments in your answer that I have to study because introduce design patterns. This is where I want to arrive, but i am still on the way. Your structure of the program is better, but the original doubt is still there. In fact stratego.run(strategy) is only the begging. After that there are other classes involved and they need the df. So I do not know if it is better to store it as global or to make the instance of the data class available as global. i can not make subclass under subclass. It would be a mess. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

If you're thinking pass by reference vs pass by value then I would suspect you are newer to Python. To my understanding, all variables are passed by reference. That is, you aren't copying the actual data every time you call a function with parameters.

If you're thinking more along the lines of global variables, you can do something like this:

```py
globvar = 0

def set_globvar_to_one():
    global globvar    # Needed to modify global copy of globvar
    globvar = 1

def print_globvar():
    print(globvar)     # No need for global declaration to read value of globvar
```

Comment: Thank you, I get this. But the program has a main function which from where I request the data and store in a variable. So I can make a variable, import in the function as global and then modify it. But then i need to make an import of the file where the global variable is stored for all the files that I have in the program. Is that correct?